# Integrating Flask-APScheduler with flask-migrate and flask Script

Tags: python, flask, apscheduler, flask-migrate, flask-script

I am not clear on how to integrate my models, using flask-script, and scheduled jobs on the same database. There appears to be some work under the hood with Flask-apscheduler where it creates the database for you.

When I run `python manage.py db init` It will create a database with an apscheduled_jobs table. Now if I run `python manage.py db migrate` I get the error:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.IntegrityError: (sqlite3.IntegrityError) UNIQUE constraint failed: apscheduler_jobs.id [SQL: 'INSERT INTO apscheduler_jobs (id, next_run_time, job_state) VALUES (?, ?, ?)'] [parameters: ('job1', 1505317109.041658, <memory at 0x000001AD6754E288>)]
```

Followed by:

```
apscheduler.jobstores.base.ConflictingIdError: 'Job identifier (job1) conflicts with an existing job'
```

The layout of my project looks something like:

[image]

In `intel\_init__.py` looks like:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_apscheduler import APScheduler
from .models import db


app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object('config.Config')
db.init_app(app)

scheduler = APScheduler()
scheduler.init_app(app)
scheduler.start()
```

`manage.py`

```
from flask_script import Manager
from flask_migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from intel_app import app, db

migrate = Migrate(app, db)

manager = Manager(app)
manager.add_command('db', MigrateCommand)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    manager.run()
```

EDIT: I moved `schedule.start()` from `intel\_init__.py` to the `run.py` module, it will work just once, for it I stop the app and then restart the app again, I get the same errors as above.